# JavaScript libarary for coding in a textarea (with proper indentation)

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, indentation

I am looking for a JavaScript libarary for coding in a textarea (with proper indentation).

I found **Behave.js** (http://jakiestfu.github.io/Behave.js/). However, that is lacking one basic feature: **Indent a new line according to the last lines indent**. It only does automatic indentation by recognizing braces and parentheses. Also, Codemirror and MarkItUp do not indent according to the last line, as far as I could see.

Do you know either an alternative library that does exactly that (and potentially more) or a way to add (or enable?) that functionality in Behave.js?

The reason why I need indentation like last line is that I want to be able to use a non standard programming language.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found the answer.

The Ace editor is the absolutely best code editor for JavaScript as far as I can see.

http://ace.c9.io/ it is developed by Cloud9 and some time ago the whole SkyWriter/Bespin team from Mozilla joined their efforts and have merged some of their features into Ace.